# CssLinkResourceTransformer is not modifying the URL's present inside css file

Tags: css, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using VersionResourceResolver [Spring Boot 1.2.0] for Cache Busting. Using below code, CSS resources gets version number but URL's inside css files doesn't get version even after using CssLinkResourceTransformer.

```
@Bean
public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
   return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/css/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer())
            .addTransformer(new AppCacheManifestTransformer());
}

.navbar-header {
    height: 58px;
    background: transparent url("../images/logo-bg.png") no-repeat left center;
}

GET https://localhost:8443/myapp/css/layout-4a5a9811a2a00e7da9b9c0f0fcfbd343.css
GET https://localhost:8443/myapp/images/logo-bg.png
```

Anything I'm missing here ? How to version the URL's inside CSS file. Thanks

**EDIT:**
Sorry I should have provided complete code of **addResourceHandlers** method which I'm having it now. Please find below the same,

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/css/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer())
            .addTransformer(new AppCacheManifestTransformer());

    registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/fonts/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new AppCacheManifestTransformer());

    registry.addResourceHandler("/html/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/html/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/images/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new AppCacheManifestTransformer());

    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/js/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new AppCacheManifestTransformer());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration only maps resources that match the pattern `"/css/**"` and `"/images/logo-bg.png"` does not match.

Could you try the following?

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**", "/images/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/css/", "/images/")
```

Note that to work with each others, resource transformers/resolvers should be declared within a unique resource handler.

Comment: @brain - thanks for your comment, I updated my question with the full code I'm using. Already I configured what you suggested, but still problem persits.

Comment: It doesn't work because you've registered your resource handling infrastructure in separate resource handlers. Try declaring everything under one `addResourceHandler`, otherwise the resource chain can't process properly resources from a separate registration.

Comment: @brain - sorry i was late to reply. Thank you for the solution, it worked after declaring everything under one `addResourceHandler`

Comment: @brain - could you update your answer with explanation about this.